# Is it possible to modify listing page codes?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have added column **discount** on **catalog_product_flat_1** table . On frontend there is dropdown for **Offers** . It has 2 options like

1. 15% Offer
2. 25% Offer

On onchange I want to show list of products based on condition i.e discount = 15%

On which function I have to apply this condition?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reach your goal by creating new product attribute and make it as a filter on your category pages, to do this, create new attribute type dropdown and set it as:

- Use In Layered Navigation - Yes
- Used in Product Listing - Yes
- Used for Sorting in Product Listing - Yes

Then reindex:

- product attributes
- product flat data

Alternatievely filter your product collection on category pages by adding:

```
$productCollection->addFieldToFilter(array('attribute'=>'offer','eq'=>'15'));
```

Comment: I created new attribute called Offer. I have used type i.e dropdown. I am not getting dropdown . Pls see attached screenshot

Comment: on which page to put this condition

Comment: Apply this condition on category page, where you getting your product collection filtered by category. Make sure to run proper reindexers first.